# Remove specific hover effect from logo while keeping it a link back to homepage

Tags: html, css

I've search for an answer on the site without any luck.  I have centered my logo in my header between my navigation links.  I've added an underline hover effect to the links which also added the effect to my logo. I figured out how to remove the hover effect from the logo (pointer-event: none;) but this also keeps me from making the logo a clickable link back to my homepage. I tried placing my logo in a separate div thinking it would be easier to fix the issue but then I spent 3 hours trying to get things properly positioned (obviously, I'm new at web building). So now I've gone back to my original code hoping to get some assistance here.  To summarize:  How can I keep the hover effect on the nav links while removing it from the logo AND keeping the logo a clickable link to the hopepage?  Thank you in advance for your help.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 20%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cc_nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin: 0 40px;
  font-family: Tenar Sans;
  font-size: .8em;
}

a {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

#logo_Claire {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 140px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.noHover {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="cc_nav" id="centered_nav">
    <a href="">HOME</a>
    <a href="">SERVICES</a>
    <a href="">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="index.html" class="noHover"><img src="images/logo_2.png" alt="Claire Crawford" id="logo_Claire" /></a>
    <a href="">PORTFOLIO</a>
    <a href="">BLOG</a>
    <a href="">GET IN TOUCH</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add below CSS-

```
.noHover:hover::before {
    background: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

and try below-working demo maybe it can help you.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 20%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cc_nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin: 0 40px;
  font-family: Tenar Sans;
  font-size: .8em;
}

a {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

#logo_Claire {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 140px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.noHover:hover::before {
  background: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="cc_nav" id="centered_nav">
    <a href="">HOME</a>
    <a href="">SERVICES</a>
    <a href="">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="index.html" class="noHover"><img src="images/logo_2.png" alt="Claire Crawford" id="logo_Claire" /></a>
    <a href="">PORTFOLIO</a>
    <a href="">BLOG</a>
    <a href="">GET IN TOUCH</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much and I appreciate the working demo!

Comment: My pleasure :) @cvc48

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, It is taking the default properties of anchor tag and you need to overwrite that so specify the important in your class properties

```
.noHover {
    pointer-events: none !important;
  }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations along with your code, so that future users can follow your ideas/code more easily. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23368982)

Answer (score 0):

Just add css for not hovering on logo and clickable

```
a.noHover:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
}
```

```css
  header{ 
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 20%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .cc_nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
  }

  a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    margin: 0 40px;
    font-family: Tenar Sans;
    font-size: .8em;

  }

  a {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        transform: translateZ(0);
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
   }

   a:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 1px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: rgb(192,192,192); 
      visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
      transform: scaleX(0);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    }

    a:hover:before {
      visibility: visible;
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
      transform: scaleX(1);
    }

    a.noHover:hover:before {
      visibility: visible;
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
      transform: scaleX(0);
    }


  #logo_Claire {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 140px;
    max-width: 300px;
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="cc_nav" id="centered_nav">
    <a href="">HOME</a>
    <a href="">SERVICES</a>
    <a href="">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="index.html" class="noHover"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/000/fff" alt="Claire Crawford" id="logo_Claire" /></a>
    <a href="">PORTFOLIO</a>
    <a href="">BLOG</a>
    <a href="">GET IN TOUCH</a>
  <div>   
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class to the navigation links only and define your link and hover styles there.

```
    <div class="cc_nav" id="centered_nav">
        <a class="hover" href="">HOME</a>
        <a class="hover" href="">SERVICES</a>
        <a class="hover" href="">ABOUT</a>
        <a href="index.html" class="noHover"><img src="images/logo_2.png" alt="Claire Crawford" id="logo_Claire" /></a>
        <a class="hover" href="">PORTFOLIO</a>
        <a class="hover" href="">BLOG</a>
        <a class="hover" href="">GET IN TOUCH</a>
        <div>
```

CSS:

```css
.cc_nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin: 0 40px;
  font-family: Tenar Sans;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hover:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.hover:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

#logo_Claire {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 140px;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

[Here is a Pen](https://codepen.io/Craeckerffm/pen/agyMvy)